# Run the Linux commands from java code ( remote operating system)

Tags: java, networking

How do I run the `ps` command from Java code? I know how to execute commands when the application is running locally, but I want to execute the command for a remote Linux operating system. For example, a Java client running on Windows. The Java client needs to connect with the remote Linux system and  needs to execute the `ps` command of Linux and get all process details.

Answer (score 1):

You can run commands using `Runtime.exec`

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec-java.lang.String-

Also, if you have key based authentication enabled you can run commands in remote systems using a `ssh` connection like this:

```
ssh user@remote.host ps -eaf
```

So, you can use something like:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ssh admin@example.com ps -eaf");
```

Comment: Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps") useful when you run the code in your local Linux machine .for example I want to get the details from remote operating system ( Linux).how I will get the ps details

Comment: I posted the answer a bit prematurely, see the edited version

Comment: Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ssh admin@example.com ps -eaf"); I need to pass the username and password of remote operating system in exec method ?? To get the all process details .please let me know if am going in wrong way

Comment: For ssh connections if you set up key based authentication beforehand there is no password prompt. Since it's hard to enter a password interactively in this situation (not to mention less secure), you should do that first. You can learn how to do that here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23291/how-to-ssh-to-remote-server-using-a-private-key and here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssh-key-based-authentication-on-a-linux-server